# Automate this function in any way?

Tags: php, arrays, json, wordpress, function

```
public function onSystemCron(&$logs, &$lastRun, $force)
    {
        $clear_tmp = true;
        $clear_logs = [];
        $log_files = $this->_application->Filter('system_admin_system_logs', []);
        foreach ($log_files as $log_name => $log) {
            $clear_logs[$log_name] = empty($log['days']) ? 365 : $log['days'];
        }
        if (!isset($lastRun[$this->_name])) {
            $lastRun[$this->_name] = [];
        } elseif (!is_array($lastRun[$this->_name])) {
            $lastRun[$this->_name] = [
                'tmp' => $lastRun[$this->_name]
            ];
        }
        if (!$force) {
            if (!empty($lastRun[$this->_name]['tmp'])
                && time() - $lastRun[$this->_name]['tmp'] < 604800
            ) {
                // Less than a week since last run so do not clear tmp
                $clear_tmp = false;
            }
```

```
<?php
namespace -\System\Tool;

class RunCronTool extends AbstractTool
{
    protected function _systemToolInfo()
    {
        return [
            'label' => __('Run cron', 'directories'),
            'description' => __('Use this tool to manually run cron.', 'directories'),
            'weight' => 15,
        ];
    }

    public function systemToolRunTask($task, array $settings, $iteration, $total, array &$storage, array &$logs)
    {
        $this->_application->callHelper('System_Cron', [&$logs, true]);

        return 1;
    }
}
```

I have an issue with a WordPress plugin. It offers a button which will force run cron. Usually, making use of this button is not necessary. I tested my WP Cron and it's working fine, so the plugin is the problem. Any data which is in relation to the plugin does not get updated by WP cron. So I'm forced to click this button manually.

So, is there any solution to automate the function of the button?

I mean, I have to open the plugin settings and click on a button to run Cron. Is there any chance to automate this process?

Can provide more information if needed.

Many thanks.

Yes, I have no idea what I'm doing thanks.

Comment: Have you tried contacting the developer of the plugin yet? If not then it might be a good idea to do so.

Answer (score 0):

When the OS wants to "kick" WordPress's cron system, it does an HTTP(S) GET to example.com/wp-cron.php .

It's possible to do this from php code, like so.

```php
if ( ! wp_doing_cron() ) {
  $url = get_site_url( null, 'wp-cron.php' );
  $req = new \WP_Http();
  $req->get( $url );
}
```

Do this last in a page view. I do it from the shutdown hook. It won't hang your page because wp-cron.php uses [fastcgi_finish_request()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fastcgi-finish-request.php) to respond immediately to its client.

This lets you run cron from your code if DISABLE_WP_CRON is true or in other circumstances where it won't get called on its own.

But be careful. Don't use this unless you really need it. It's a bad idea to work around a site owner's need to set DISABLE_WP_CRON.

Comment: Hey man 

Really thankful for your answer, appreciate it

But heres the catch..

Im a noob with lil to none experience.

How can i test your solution?

I know how to disable WPs Cron. But what about the code? Where to put it? Also into the wp-config.php ? And do i need to replace some data inside the code?

Many thanks

Comment: It's not totally clear to me how the code you showed us relates to WordPress. What is this `AbstractTool` class you're extending. Are you developing the plugin yourself, or did you get it online? What plugin is it?